# Save React App to static html when no new data to update available

Tags: html, reactjs

I am working on a Java based thick client app. Now we have a small react app that opens as part of user interaction to show some UI that gets updated as I poll from with react app to get new updated json data and user sees the real time update. And this update is for small duration and after a point it won't update as no new data and polling stops. Now what I want to be able to do is to export this app with the current json data in to static html for the user so its viewable when a html file is opened with no dependency on any other thing.

note: I separately have acces to the json data(json file).

What I tried:

I edited the package.json

```
 "homepage": ".",
```

I added a hardcoded json file to be fed to my app instead of making call to backend like below and this part of code may be I can manage by creating a cutom NODE_ENV(only for exporting) in my react code

```
import jsonData from "./data.json";
```

Now if I build the app using "npm run build", If I click on the index.html, **all works fine**.

But as part of "npm run build" the "data.json" file is been merged to "*chunk.js", is there a way have this json file separated(not merged to *.chunk.js) file, so I can simply update the "data.json" file with right/new content and send the build contents to the user which is viewable when index.html is opened

Also please suggest if any better way to achieve this

TIA

Comment: When u use import, it will be packed in the building, i think you could use a static url and load the json seperatly

Comment: Thanks, could you please give more detail. I tried ad saw it made it inline in the main*.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be little hack. But I ended up achieveing this.

- Using a Java api on demand I ended up location the main*.js file using the manifest.json and replaced a dummy json content I had placed. That is I made all the json content inline in the main*.js file and put all the image resouces in the current dir. Now opening the index.html renders all fine.